# how to duplicate jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

My application uses `jQuery modal dialog`. At the moment I can only move the dialog within the context of the parent page. Now the challenging part is, without making a major re-factoring: How do I change this dialog to a new window so that i can move it to another screen?

**Edit:**

`window.open` takes an `url`, which renders the entire page. I only need to render the section/content of the `div` (which is currently in the `modal dialog`). Also currently the div (`modal dialog`) is using `setInterval` to auto-refresh the content.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try This Code:**

```
$('#link').click(function () {    
     window.open('http://www.example.com','mywindow','width=400,height=200')
});
```

**Edit :**

It is working code.Through this code you can render a section/content of a page in a dialog try it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jquery Dialog Demo</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
                    $( "#div1" ).dialog({
                    height: 140,
                    modal: true
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <p>Hi we will do it.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="button"  id="btn1" name="btn1" value="Opne Dialog"/>
    <!-- content goes here-->
</body>
</html>
```

By this code use can open your particular page in another window.

Comment: not a solution.   window.open takes an url, which renders the entire page.. i only need to render the section/content of the div (which is currently in modal dialog).